# Adding a text with spacing in math mode

Tags: math-mode, overleaf, text

I have a text inside mathmode in latex and I would like the text to be separated from the equation with some spaces. How can I do this? Example code below

```
\begin{gather*}
A^2 = B^2 + C^2  \text{[Pythagaros theorem]}
\end{gather*}
```

Comment: Insert `\hspace{<len>}` between the two elements, where `<len>` is something like `2cm`.

Comment: You also have `\quad` or `\qquad`. Whatever suits you.

Comment: @Werner I would probably suggest learning users to use `\quad` and `\qquad` to keep these spaces unified. Learning them to use `\hspace` is just opening up a can of worms

Comment: @Werner I have done this but this changes the alignment of my equation.

Comment: @GitGoodCodes: So you want the equation to be centered within the text block, but the text to be on the right, correct? For that you can use `\[ <eqn> \qquad \makebox[0pt][l]{<text>} \]`. If you want it flush with the right margin, you can use `\tag*{<text>}`.

Comment: That worked perfectly. Many thanks!